# DHTMLX Scheduler recurring events

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dhtmlx

I have trouble with the `DHTMLX scheduler` specifically around recurring events.

I have tried to follow the documentation found here http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/recurring-events-calendar-view-asp-net.aspx. However can't seem to get it working.

I can create the basic scheduler without any issues. The issue I now have is that any event that gets created won't save to the DB. This is what I have so far.

**Model:**

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[DHXJson(Alias = "id")]
public int Id { get; set; }

[DHXJson(Alias = "text")]
public string Description { get; set; }

[DHXJson(Alias = "start_date")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[DHXJson(Alias = "end_date")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

[DHXJson(Alias="event_length")]
public int event_length { get; set; }

[DHXJson(Alias = "rec_type")]
public string rec_type { get; set; }

[DHXJson(Alias = "event_pid")]
public int event_pid { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Save(int? id, FormCollection actionValues)
{
    var action = new DataAction(actionValues);
    ApplicationDbContext data = new ApplicationDbContext();
    try
    {
        var changedEvent = (Appointment)DHXEventsHelper.Bind(typeof(Appointment), actionValues);
        //operations with recurring events require some additional handling
        bool isFinished = deleteRelated(action, changedEvent, data);
        if (!isFinished)
        {
            switch (action.Type)
            {

                case DataActionTypes.Insert:
                    data.Appointment.Add(changedEvent);
                    if (changedEvent.rec_type == "none")//delete one event from the serie
                        action.Type = DataActionTypes.Delete;
                    break;
                case DataActionTypes.Delete:
                    changedEvent = data.Appointment.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == action.SourceId);
                    data.Appointment.Remove(changedEvent);
                    break;
                default:// "update"   
                    var eventToUpdate = data.Appointment.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == action.SourceId);
                    DHXEventsHelper.Update(eventToUpdate, changedEvent, new List<string>() { "id" });
                    break;
            }
        }
        data.SaveChanges();
        action.TargetId = changedEvent.Id;
    }
    catch
    {
        action.Type = DataActionTypes.Error;
    }

    return (new AjaxSaveResponse(action));
}
protected bool deleteRelated(DataAction action, Appointment changedEvent, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    bool finished = false;
    if ((action.Type == DataActionTypes.Delete || action.Type == DataActionTypes.Update) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(changedEvent.rec_type))
    {
       // context.Recurrings.DeleteAllOnSubmit(from ev in context.Recurrings where ev.event_pid == changedEvent.id select ev);
    }
    if (action.Type == DataActionTypes.Delete && (changedEvent.event_pid != 0 && changedEvent.event_pid != null))
    {
    //    Recurring changed = (from ev in context.Recurrings where ev.id == action.TargetId select ev).Single();
     //   changed.rec_type = "none";
        finished = true;
    }
    return finished;
}
```

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the change save method return value to "ContentResult". Also Look into your ApplicationDbContext and see if you can pull some hard-coded db values from that table when your index loads. Here is a copy of mine. I had the same problems until I used linq to classes to create the model/EF and my context is based on that. I was having the same issue when I created my own "light-weight" interface because I didn't want to use EF.

```
public ContentResult Save(int? id, FormCollection actionValues)
    {
        var action = new DataAction(actionValues);
        var context = new SchedulerDataContext();
        Int64 source_id = Int64.Parse(actionValues["id"]);
        try
        {
            var changedDelEvent = (Delivery)DHXEventsHelper.Bind(typeof(Delivery), actionValues);
            var changedRecEvent = (Recurring)DHXEventsHelper.Bind(typeof(Recurring), actionValues);
            //operations with recurring events require some additional handling
            bool isFinished = deleteRelated(action, changedRecEvent, context);
            if (!isFinished)
            {
                switch (action.Type)
                {
                    case DataActionTypes.Insert:
                        context.Recurrings.InsertOnSubmit(changedRecEvent);
                        context.SubmitChanges();
                        break;
                    case DataActionTypes.Delete:
                        changedRecEvent = context.Recurrings.SingleOrDefault(d => d.id == source_id);
                        if (changedRecEvent != null)
                        {
                            context.Recurrings.DeleteOnSubmit(changedRecEvent);
                        }
                        context.SubmitChanges();
                        break;
                    default:// "update"                                        
                        var eventToUpdate = context.Deliveries.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DeliveryID == source_id);
                        DHXEventsHelper.Update(eventToUpdate, changedRecEvent, new List<string> { "id" });
                        if (eventToUpdate != null && eventToUpdate.RouteID != changedRecEvent.id)
                        {
                            var routeToUpdate = context.Routes.SingleOrDefault(d => d.RouteID == changedRecEvent.id);
                            eventToUpdate.Route = routeToUpdate;
                        }
                        context.SubmitChanges();
                        break;
                }
                action.TargetId = changedRecEvent.id;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            action.Type = DataActionTypes.Error;
        }

        return (new AjaxSaveResponse(action));           
    }
```

Comment: You'll notice I'm trying to get the recurring to work, which is why I've two "changed", but the crud for events w/out recurring works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The recurring extension (dhtmlxscheduler_recurring.js) doesn't recognize the DHXJson Alias annotations that you are using on your entity class properties (extremely frustrating). Therefore, you must name your entity class columns/properties exactly how the dhtmlxscheduler_recurring.js is expecting them, even though the base scheduler API gives you the option for custom naming using the DHXJson alias annotations.